# Editing property of foreignkey object

Tags: python, django, models

I am trying to access a ForeignKey object in Django, but only manage to show its values, not to edit them.

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, primary_key=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    houseNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=63)

class MainClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    aShippingAddress = models.ForeignKey(ShippingAddress)
```

this would be an example. I would now like to make the values of the ShippingAddress model directly accesible and editable within the main class. Right now though I manage to only access the object itself, not every value of it directly.

(admin.py)

```
def editZipCode(self, obj):
            return obj.aShippingAddress.zipCode
```

this way I manage to show each value at least, but that's it.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to have multiple `ShippingAddress`es per object? If yes, you are doing it wrong. Currently you have multiple `MainClass` objects for each `ShippingAddress`.

Comment: I would like to have a selection of all already added shipping addresses (+ making them editable). Right now I am only able to add an object (that is always called x object) and then edit all values at once: http://i.imgur.com/5mh3btc.png . My goal is to have a dropdown for every value of x in Model y. Currently I am only able to do this by returning one attribute, for example name, but that doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin):

```
class MainClassInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MainClass

class ShippingAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = (MainClassInline,)
```

Comment: I tried this out earlier today, but whenever I created a new object, I ended up with something like this: http://i.imgur.com/McR52NF.png . A blank page without the options to select already created elements (books) from another object, which is what I would need.

Is that possible, using inlines?